# Select function returns unexpected result

Tags: filtering

Recently I notice one fact about the `Select` function that I do not understand. For example,

```
Select[3 a b + 3 a c, ! FreeQ[#, d] &]
```

> 0 (* as expected*)

However, if I try

```
Select[3 a (b + c), ! FreeQ[#, d] &] (*I just factorize the same expression above*)
```

I got instead

> 1

The only difference between these two expressions are the expression heads. But in the documentation center for `Select`, it says `The object list can have any head, not necessarily List.` So I guess `Select` will work differently for `Times` compared with `Plus`. I'm curious about why they differ and could someone help? Thanks in advance. By the way, I'm using Mathematica 11.3.0.0

Comment: The reason is that `Times[]` evaluates to `1`. Try  `Select[fun[a,b], !FreeQ[#,d]&]` and then it becomes clear.

Comment: @RolfMertig Ah! You are right! Did not realize that `Times[]` gives 1, I should have checked the documentation center for `Times`. But now I understand! I guess I can live happily with the rest of the day! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Rolf's comment, notice the following behavior of [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) and [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times):

```
Plus[]
Times[]
```

> 0
>
> 1

This is what you're seeing in your code. One way to confirm this is to use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint) for the [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) version:

```
TracePrint[
    Select[3 a b + 3 a c, !FreeQ[#,d]&],
    _Plus,
    TraceAction->Print@*FullForm
]
```

> HoldForm[Plus[Times[3,a,b],Times[3,a,c]]]
>
> HoldForm[Plus[]]
>
> 0

vs the [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint) for the [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) version:

```
TracePrint[
    Select[3 a (b+c), !FreeQ[#,d]&],
    _Times,
    TraceAction->Print@*FullForm
]
```

> HoldForm[Times[3,a,Plus[b,c]]]
>
> HoldForm[Times[]]
>
> 1